# ASP.NET Core 3.1 with Razor pages, api controllers and IdentityServer4

Tags: asp.net-core, identityserver4, razor-pages

I'm creating a boilerplate for ASP.NET Core 3.1 projects with Razor page, api controller and IdentityServer4. The full source code is in my [Github](https://github.com/erossini/AdminWebCore).

The configuration in the *Startup.cs* is

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddAuthentication("Bearer")
        .AddJwtBearer("Bearer", options => {
            options.Authority = "https://localhost:44301";
            options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
        });

    services.AddIdentityServer()
        .AddDeveloperSigningCredential() 
        //not something we want to use in a production environment
        .AddInMemoryIdentityResources(InMemoryConfig.GetIdentityResources())
        .AddTestUsers(InMemoryConfig.GetUsers())
        .AddInMemoryClients(InMemoryConfig.GetClients());
    }
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }
    else
    {
        app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
        app.UseHsts();
    }

    app.UseIdentityServer();

    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    app.UseStaticFiles();

    app.UseRouting();

    app.UseAuthorization();

    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapRazorPages();
        endpoints.MapControllers();
    });

    app.UseOpenApi();
    app.UseSwaggerUi3();
}
```

I configured the IdentityServer4 with **InMemoryConfig**. If I use Postman, I have a valid token as result.

[image: Postman]

The problem occurs when I call the webapi from the url `https://localhost:44301/api/Account`. When I decorate the apicontroller with `[Authorize]`, I'm using Postman to call it and I pass as authorization the bearer token I've just create and I already receive `404 Not Found`. If I try to use Swagger for calling this function and I pass the token, there is no result.

[image]

The Swagger page is recognizing correctly all apis. Without the `[Authorize]` decoration I can test my apis.

[image: Swagger without authorization]

When I add the authorization and I add the token to my request, Swagger doesn't show anything, oh well, 404.

[image: Swagger with authorization]

I don't know if this is a configuration problem or something different.

### Update

I googled a lot and I found a [post](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/9039) on the ASP.NET core repo and I tried to update `ConfigureService` like

```
// this order seems important for .NET: 
// first AddIdentityServer then AddAuthentication
services.AddIdentityServer()
    .AddDeveloperSigningCredential()
    .AddInMemoryIdentityResources(InMemoryConfig.GetIdentityResources())
    .AddTestUsers(InMemoryConfig.GetUsers())
    .AddInMemoryClients(InMemoryConfig.GetClients());

services.AddAuthentication(options =>
    {
        options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    })
    // necessary, even if you don't use BearerAuth.
    .AddJwtBearer();
```

then I changed

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }
    else
    {
        app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
        // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
        app.UseHsts();
    }

    app.UseIdentityServer();

    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    app.UseStaticFiles();

    app.UseRouting();

    // this order seems important for .NET
    // first UseAuthorization and then UseAuthentication
    app.UseAuthorization();
    app.UseAuthentication();

    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapRazorPages();
        endpoints.MapControllers();
    });

    app.UseOpenApi();
    app.UseSwaggerUi3();
}
```

Now I receive `401 Unauthorized` instead of `404 Non found`. Apparently, ASP.NET Core redirects automatically to a login page.

Comment: Putting `app.UseAuthorization()` before `app.UseAuthentication()` is the opposite of what you should do when defining your [middleware order](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?view=aspnetcore-3.1#middleware-order). But there is another caveat, `app.UseIdentityServer()` already adds the authentication middleware! Be aware of this because it can configure the authentication middleware out of order. Move your `app.UseIdentityServer()` so it goes after `app.UseRouting()` and before `app.UseAuthorization()`.

Comment: Thank you @Dennis1679 I changed the order but I'm facing the same issue Nothing changes.